# React native image slider box not running properly

Tags: react-native

```
import { SliderBox } from "react-native-image-slider-box";

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at ./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js
```

I am trying to use image slider box in a react native app and I don't understand what does the error mean. I have already installed the package and does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the plugin here but don't worry I'll guide you on how

**Step 1**

**1)** Install the [patch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) into your project, as per the instructions.

**2)** Install deprecated-react-native-prop-types by running npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types or yarn add deprecated-react-native-prop-types.

**Step 2**

Update the Carousel.js remove ViewPropTypes from react-native  and update the style as well

> ./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js

```
+ import { ViewPropTypes } from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' 
- import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native'; 



-   slideStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
-   containerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
-   contentContainerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
    
    
+   containerCustomStyle:  ViewPropTypes?.style ?? View.propTypes?.style,
+   slideStyle: ViewPropTypes?.style ?? View.propTypes?.style ,
+   contentContainerCustomStyle:  ViewPropTypes?.style ?? View.propTypes?.style,



Step 3

In package.json

 "scripts": {
   + "patch": "npx patch-package",
   + "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
```

Run bellow commands

```
npx patch-package react-native-snap-carousel
```

Comment: The code ```containerCustomStyle:  ViewPropTypes?.style ?? View.propTypes?.style ?? () => null``` could not work and show syntax error

Comment: show me the issue

Comment: remove this "?? () => null"

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: I need some time to check if it really works